# Saving data from a form field in a Titanium app

Tags: javascript, input, titanium, storage

I am writing a program on titanium using html and javascript, and I have a form settings page that sets the values for other form fields I need to save the data entered in the text boxes and load them the next time the start the program or reload the page, how would I do this in a simple way?

```
<div id="formh">
    <form id="form">
        <select name="test" id="test">
            <option id="op1" value="1">1234</option>
            <option id="op2" value="2">2134</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="st">
    <form name="settings">
        Op1 Value<input type="text" value="" id="inputOpt1" />
        Op2 Value<input type="text" value="" id="inputOpt2" />
    </form>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hSyY3/

Comment: Why are you using titanium this way? Don't really understand why you are using an html file at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the form's onSubmit event (or onChange for the inputs if you don't want a submit button), you can save the settings using the [Titanium.Database](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Database-module) or [Titanium.App.Properties](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.App.Properties-module) - I think the latter would be more appropriate in this case.  Here would be an example in jQuery (for simplicity, though you could do it without):

```
$("form[name='settings']").submit(function(){
  var val1 = $('input#inputOpt1').val();
  Titanium.App.Properties.setString("opt1", val1);
  var val2 = $('input#inputOpt2').val();
  Titanium.App.Properties.setString("opt2", val2);
});
```

Then, basically do the opposite for the other form to retrieve the Properties from Titanium and set the input field values.

**UPDATE**

The full example (again, not sure that I completely understand the desired interaction):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form[name='settings'] input").change(function(){
    // these will happen on every change to the input values
    var val1 = $('input#inputOpt1').val();
    Titanium.App.Properties.setString("opt1", val1);
    var val2 = $('input#inputOpt2').val();
    Titanium.App.Properties.setString("opt2", val2);
  });

  // these will only happen right after the page loads
  var setting1 = Titanium.App.Properties.getString("opt1");
  $("form#form op1").val(setting1);
  var setting2 = Titanium.App.Properties.getString("opt2");
  $("form#form op2").val(setting2);
});
```

Comment: what is th opposite? besides, its the same form, but it defaults to blank when its reloaded. please explain, i'm new to this

Comment: would i use getstring instead of setstring?

Comment: would this work? `$("form[name='settings']").load(function(){
  var val1 = $('input#inputOpt1').val();
  Titanium.App.Properties.getString("opt1");
  var val2 = $('input#inputOpt2').val();
  Titanium.App.Properties.getString("opt2");
});`

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want the first form populated from the values that were previously entered in the second form, yes?  Something like this (adding above).

Comment: no no i want the same form to be filled with values that were entered in the previous session (on that same form)